# How can I combine 'must' and 'should' with AND condition?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I need to return documents from ES that satisfy these 2 conditions: at least one of conditionIds in the `should` clause should match the `conditionId` property of documents AND at least one of the categoryIds should match.

I tried this query but this does not work:

```
{
"query": {
"bool": {
"should": [
{
"match": {
"conditionIds": "5e24b2f02bd0d76df4615c82"
}
},
{
"match": {
"conditionIds": "5e24b2f02bd0d76df4615c82"
}
},
],
"filter": [
{
"query_string": {
"default_field": "name",
"query": "*"
}
}
],
"must": [
{
"match": {
"categoryIds": “fc57hj5-0bx-4sha-aw7u-c11cd32eec2a"
}
},
{
"match": {
"categoryIds": "d2c5a505-01bb-41ba-ad7e-c11cd32eec2a"
}
}
]
}
}
}
```

And my document schema:

```
                "conditionIds": [
                    "5e24b2f02bd0d76df4615c81"
                ],
                "createdAt": "2020-05-08T19:07:11.756Z",
                "categoryIds": [
                    "7b913ed0-54e0-4857-b114-92f65631b6a6"
                ],
                "minPrice": 71.47,
                "locations": [
                    {
                        "continent": "GLOBAL",
                        "lon": 0,
                        "lat": 0
                    }
                ],
                "id": "c64d03d6-4248-416c-bc07-c42b50548e3b",
                "maxPrice": 71.47,
                "statusIds": [
                    "5e24b2f02bd0d76df4615c81"
                ],
                "childrenCount": 1,
                "updatedAt": "2020-05-08T19:07:11.756Z"
            }
```

Comment: can you format your query, it's not a proper JSON.

Answer (score 0):

```
     {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": {
            "match": {
              "conditionIds": {
                "query": "5e24b2f02bd0d76df4615c82 5e24b2f02bd0d76df4615c82",
                "operator": "OR"
              }
            }
          },
          "filter": [
            {
              "query_string": {
                "default_field": "name",
                "query": "*"
              }
            }
          ],
          "must": {
            "match": {
              "categoryIds": {
                "query": "d2c5a505-01bb-41ba-ad7e-c11cd32eec2a d2c5a505-01bb-41ba-ad7e-c11cd32eec2a",
                "operator": "OR"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }


// OR Try the below one which matches most


{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "name",
            "query": "*"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "categoryIds": {
              "query": "d2c5a505-01bb-41ba-ad7e-c11cd32eec2a d2c5a505-01bb-41ba-ad7e-c11cd32eec2a",
              "operator": "OR"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "conditionIds": {
              "query": "5e24b2f02bd0d76df4615c82 5e24b2f02bd0d76df4615c82",
              "operator": "OR"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: By default it's always OR but I explicitly mentioned but try this, see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested bool query to do the same. You can read more about it from [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html).

### Mapping :

```
"mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "categoryIds": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "conditionId": {
                    "type": "text"
                }
            }
        }
```

Documents that are indexed are :

### Doc1 :

```
"_source": {
        "conditionId": "5e24b2f02bd0d76df4615c82",
        "categoryIds": "fc57hj5-0bx-4sha-aw7u-c11cd32eec2a"
 }
```

### Doc2:

```
"_source": {
    "conditionId": "5e24b2f02bd0d76df4615c81",
    "categoryIds": "d2c5a505-01bb-41ba-ad7e-c11cd32eec2a"
  }
```

### Doc3 :

```
"_source": {
        "conditionId": "5e24b2f02bd0d76df4615c82",
        "categoryIds": "test1"
}
```

### Doc4 :

```
"_source": {
        "conditionId": "test2",
        "categoryIds": "d2c5a505-01bb-41ba-ad7e-c11cd32eec2a"
}
```

Search query is :

### Query :

```
{
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [
                {
                    "bool" : {
                        "should" : [
                            {
                                "match" :{
                                    "conditionId": "5e24b2f02bd0d76df4615c81"
                                }
                            },
                                {
                                "match" :{
                                    "conditionId": "5e24b2f02bd0d76df4615c82"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "minimum_should_match":"1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool" : {
                        "should" : [
                            {
                                "match" :{
                                "categoryIds": "fc57hj5-0bx-4sha-aw7u-c11cd32eec2a"
                                }
                            },
                                {
                                "match" :{
                                    "categoryIds": "d2c5a505-01bb-41ba-ad7e-c11cd32eec2a"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "minimum_should_match":"1"
                    }   
                }

            ]
        }
    }
}
```

### Hits :

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 6.2170887,
        "_source": {
          "conditionId": "5e24b2f02bd0d76df4615c82",
          "categoryIds": "fc57hj5-0bx-4sha-aw7u-c11cd32eec2a"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 3.920197,
        "_source": {
          "conditionId": "5e24b2f02bd0d76df4615c81",
          "categoryIds": "d2c5a505-01bb-41ba-ad7e-c11cd32eec2a"
        }
      }
    ]
```